# > Could not get unknown property 'mainClass' for object of type org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.DefaultJavaApplication

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, java-11

I just updated the build file

```
application {
    mainClassName = 'main class'
}
```

to

```
application {
    mainClass.set('main class')
}
```

as I was receiving the following warning

```
The JavaApplication.setMainClassName(String) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Use #getMainClass().set(...) instead.
```

```
gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.6
------------------------------------------------------------
```

but now my build is failing with the error :

```
> Could not get unknown property 'mainClass' for object of type org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.DefaultJavaApplication.
```

how can I fix these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work – as long as you’re really using Gradle 7.6. I’ve just (successfully) tried this myself with the following build file:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

/*
application {
    mainClassName = 'com.foo.Bar'
}
*/

application {
    mainClass.set('com.foo.Bar')
}
```

Can you make sure that you’re always using the same (somewhat recent) Gradle version? For example, you showed that you’ve run `gradle --version`. Is there maybe a [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) in your project for a Gradle version older than 6.4? In that case, if you run something like `./gradlew projects`, you’d get the error while with `gradle projects` you wouldn’t.

FWIW, you can upgrade the Gradle Wrapper as follows (but make sure to use `mainClassName` during the upgrade): `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.6`